# External table not in expected format

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I know this question have been asked couple of times here but I followed the suggestions and still getting an error : `External table is not in expected format.`
My application has DataGrid that displays properly the excel file content and when I refresh the DataGrid it shows added row in excel file.But when I open the excel file to check if the row is added ,it's not-no new row is saved.

I'd appreciate your help.

My Wpf application has a connection string in App.config:

```
add name="ExcelConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=excel_file\\events2.xlsx;Extended Properties=&quot;Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES&quot;"
```

I'm using OLEDB to connect with excel file:

```
public Events()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection excelConnection;
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ExcelConnectionString"].ToString();

    excelConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    try
    {
        String sql = null;
        excelConnection.Open();
        myCommand.Connection = excelConnection;
        sql = "Select * from [events$]";
        myCommand.CommandText = sql;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter dataAdp = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(myCommand);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("events");
        dataAdp.Fill(dt);
        dgData.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        dataAdp.Update(dt);

        excelConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        excelConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need tp post your connection string.

Comment: I did,it's in the post.

Comment: Your Data Source is not correct. it must be a valid file name with a valid path. "excel_file\\" is not a valid path.

Comment: excel_file is a folder location within projects folder.The datagrid is displaying data from excel file so I guess the path is correct.